# Docker container failed to spin up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/tadhglewis/issue-status) in `Github` in a `Docker` container. It is a simple reactjs status application.

I tried to run this in my local environment with following commands after cloning:

```
// install dependencies
npm install

// and then
npm start
```

And works totally fine.

Then I did the same thing with a `Dockerfile`, as below:

```
# Use whatever version you are running locally (see node -v)
FROM node:12.13

WORKDIR /

COPY package.json /


RUN npm install

COPY . /


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And when I am using `docker-compose.yml` to build this as below using `docker-compose up --build -d`:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  frontend_common:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:3000
```

But the container EXITS and when I try to see the logs, it gives no error but following output:

```
> issue-status@0.1.0 start /
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://<Redacted>/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Can someone help me where I am being gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, this is a common issue that you are facing with react-scripts@3.4.1. You can follow the issue and see the recommended workarounds such as [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688):

Either downgrade or add the [`following line`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688#issuecomment-602110747) in your docker-compose file:

```
stdin_open: true
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  frontend_common:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    stdin_open: true
```